# How to upgrade to 12.04 from 10.10 with a dell?

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I skip over releases?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases)

I bought Dell Inspiron N5040 yesterday and it seems to have 32bit Ubuntu 10.10 installed. I want to upgrade to 12.04 LTS using network installation. Note, updater can't find 12.04.

Furthermore, if I change long term to normal releases then updater can find 11.04, but it will fail because on an authentication error.

Comment: Since you bought this yesterday, I would advise you to go with a clean 12.04 install.

Comment: @fossfreedom : I installed Chromium OS (*troll face*). Note, i had to use prebuilt image, because compiling it requires 64bit system. After i got it installed on systems HDD and flash working, it was beautiful. Then I realized, i could just run it inside Ubuntu and clean installed 64bit 12.04 LTS. Just helpful tip for someone who is assuming that "10.10 > 11.04 > 11.10 > 12.04." will just work - it does not (trying to fix that will just waste your time).

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1948465) suggests a direct upgrade is impossible I'm afraid. That concurs with what I thought when I saw your question too, as I'm sure I've seen this asked before. I would suggest backing up then installing clean for the best experience.

Comment: It is ... clean, because its new.

Comment: Then you can skip the back up :-), though I'm afraid I'm still fairly sure Ubuntu doesn't support upgrades that skip a release unless it's LTS to LTS :-(